# Better way of creating an array and pushing values

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm trying to achieve an array that is a collection of the first element of each row achieved by reading a CSV file.

I have the following:

```
ids = []
CSV.foreach(filename) do |row|
  ids << row[0]
end
ids
```

Is there any way to write this in one line? Or neater than that?

Comment: What do you expect to be the result of reading without it being an array? Does that make sense?

Comment: If there's a better way to approach it please let me know. My only end aim is to return an array made of the first element of each row of the CSV

Comment: `CSV.foreach(filename).map(&:first)` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ids = CSV.read(filename).map(&:first)`

Comment: Works perfectly - many thanks will accept when I can (not sure who downvoted you)

Comment: Your edit after my answer made your answer look essentially the same as mine.

Comment: @sawa using read over foreach was an improvement but it didn't answer the full question of getting the first element and assigning the value to ids.

Comment: _"using read over foreach was an improvement"_ – `read` parses the entire file into an array, whereas `foreach` reads it row by row. The latter is probably more memory efficient, especially for huge CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do:

```
CSV.read(filename)
```

If you wanted to collect only the first column, then:

```
CSV.read(filename).map{|row| row[0]}
```